# loadMore для angularjs в ajax запросе help please!

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, get

Доброго времени суток всем.
Хотел спросить, как реализовать кнопку loadMore для данных, полученных при ajax запросе.

Вот мой html кусочек, с которого начинается цикл вывода данных.

```
...
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: '-created_at' | limitTo: 5">
...
<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="loadMore()">LoadMore</button>
```

Вот мой запрос GET на удаленный api.

```
    $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/pages/paveligorevich55@icloud.com/comments",
    params : {
        'count' : $scope.n,
        'offset' : 0
    }
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
    $scope.n = response.data.length;
    $scope.loadMore = function(){
        $scope.n = $scope.n + 5;
    }; 
    console.log(response.data.length);
});
```

Поправьте пожалуйста - если есть что то не правильное синтаксически или симатически.
Вот что выдает консоль `console.log(response);`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему у вас все переменные (`data`, `name`, `date`) равны одному и тому же (`response.data`)?

Comment: Хороший вопрос конечно, но я так понял, опять же я новичок в этом, что скоупом я создаю переменную допустим name равную массиву данных data эвента response

Comment: Ну, можно и так сказать. Просто  у вас сейчас во всех переменных находится одно и тоже значение `response.data`. Это как минимум странно, а скорее всего - ошибка.

Comment: Я попробую удалить их, но по-моему без этого я не мог выводить данные. @StepanKasyanenko

Comment: Попробуйте написать в `console.log($scope)` и увидите, что там одинаковые данные.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я попробую. А что на счёт моего основного вопроса? Вы сможете помочь ? (Кнопка loadmore)

Comment: Сложно ответить без полноценного примера. Но общий смысл такой: при получении новых данных записывайте их в `$scope.data`. Например `$scope.data = $scope.data.concat(response.data);`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko вы знаете, обошелся я и без прочих переменных) 
осталось понять, как вот сделать то, что вы написали
Я пытался сделать через `$scope.limit= 5;

// loadMore function
$scope.loadMore = function() {
  $scope.limit = $scope.limit +5;
}`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Почему то при добавлении новых комментариев на странице в массои данных json на сервере - данных замещаются(не знаю как корректнее сказать) и json сервера в любом случае отдает только 5 элементов - так и должно быть?

Comment: Что бы не пытаться выразить код словами, что не легко, приведите код! Отредактируйте ваш вопрос, добавив актуальный код. Также, добавьте пример данных, который возвращает сервер.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я отредактировал текущий код, проблема в том, что API почему-то ограничивает Array до 5 элементов, и при добавлении нового комментария - старые почему то не выводит сам json

Comment: Ну это вопрос к вашему АПИ, почему он выдает 5 записей. Мы этого точно не знаем))

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тогда другой вопрос - как задать в params : {} запроса count который изначально принимает integer но по клику на loadMore будет увеличивать свое значение?

Comment: Добавляете в запрос в  `params : {count: $scope.limit }`. С чем проблема?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko тогда функция loadMore() не работает при клике, 
а мне нужно, что бы параметр передавался в count  - но этого не происходит, зато если поставить там к примеру "99999999" - то все будет прекрасно работать - но это похоже на бред ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общий смысл такой: при получении новых данных записывайте их в `$scope.data`.

Пример кода:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.offset = 0;
    $scope.data = [];
    // Загружаем 15 комментов при загрузке контроллера
    loadComments($scope.offset);

    $scope.loadMore = function() {
      $scope.offset += 15;
      // Загружаем 15 при нажатии на кнопку
      loadComments($scope.offset);
    };

    function loadComments(offset) {
      return MyService.getComments(15, offset).then(function(res) {
        $scope.data = $scope.data.concat(res.data);
      });
    }
  })
  .service('MyService', function($http) {
    return {
      getComments: function(count, offset) {
        return $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: "http://frontend-test.pingbull.com/pages/paveligorevich55@icloud.com/comments",
          params: {
            'count': count,
            'offset': offset
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy: '-created_at' | limitTo: 5">
      {{item|json}}
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="loadMore()">LoadMore</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы простите, я не могу проврить правильность ответа, но думаю он верный, но пока это слишком сложно для меня, но я буду разбираться

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич по моему мнению, если данный код для вас сложен, то вам следует начать с изучения азов программирования на `js`. После этого уже можете браться за изучение `angularjs`.

Comment: я уже разобрался, но спасибо за совет! И за помощь! Предпочитаю учится на заданиях по-сложнее, ибо выполняя задачи, по своим возможностям, считаю, что ничему новому ты не учишься